# Defining inverses of ellipsoid w.r.t. proving being a regular surfaces

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I'm using Do Carmo's Differential Geometry book, and currently stuyding the section about regular surfaces. The book gives an elloborate definition with the three conditions a surface needs to satisfy to be a regular surface. However, there are some propositions which makes checking whether a surface is regular more easy. I'm having troubles with an exaple of the following proposition:

**Proposition.**  $\quad$ If $f : U\to \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$  is a differentiable function and $a \in f(U)$ is a regular value of $f$, then $f^{-1}(a)$ is a regular surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Then, the books illustrates the proposition with the following example

**Example.** $\quad$ The ellipsoid

\begin{equation}
\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1
\end{equation}
is a regular surface. In fact, it is the set $f^{-1}(0)$ where 
\begin{equation}
f(x,y,z) = \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} - 1
\end{equation}
is a differentaible function and $0$ is a regular value of $f$. This follows from the fact that the partial derivatives vanish only at the point $(0,0,0)$, which does not belong to $f^{-1}(0)$

**My problems.** $\quad$ I'm not too confident about computing an inverse for such an equation. Why is the ellipsoid the set $f^{-1}(0)$? Is there a derviation or explanation? I do not understand what $f^{-1}(0)$ in this context means, since there is only only dimensions, namely $0$, instaead of the three dimensions $(0,0,0)$. Also, I do not see the value substituted anywhere. I hope my question is clear! For reference, this problem occurs at page 63, example 2, section 2.2 from Do Carmo Differential Geometry and Surfaces, second edition.

Comment: If $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2=1$, then $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2-1=0$ and conversely.  That is the meaning of the ellipsoid being $f^{-1}(0)$ where $f(x,y,z):=x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2-1$.

Comment: But where does the $0$ come from? Where did you apply it? For me, it feels as the same reasoning as the reasoning from the book that gives me troubles

Comment: The $0$ in $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2-1=0$ comes from moving the $1$ to the other side.  Calling the LHS $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2-1$ by a special name "$f(x,y,z)$" then tells you $f(x,y,z)=0$, i.e., $(x,y,z)\in f^{-1}(0)$, where $f^{-1}$ is the inverse image $f^{-1}(t)=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid f(x,y,z)=t\}$ for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ah, like that! the last sentence clarified things :)